# CKfinder- Dynamic User folder -Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using Asp.NET MVC 5 to build a web application. I downloaded Ckeditor and CKfinder Connector for ASP.NET. I was able to follow the instructions and get Ckeditor and Ckfinder integration to work.

I am trying to figure out how I can have dynamic folder directory in CkFinder per logged in user. According to the instructions provided in http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/howto.html#howto_private_folders it tells you to do that in connectorBuilder .SetRequestConfiguration. The problem is that ConnectorBuilder is being setup on the startup and the user logs in after that?

Here is the code that i have now where everything works except the icons

```cs
using DearColleagueV2.Models;

[assembly: Microsoft.Owin.OwinStartup(typeof(DearColleagueV2.Startup))]

namespace DearColleagueV2
{
    using System.Configuration;

    using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Config;
    using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Builders;
    using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Logs;
    using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Host.Owin;
    using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Logs.NLog;
    using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.KeyValue.EntityFramework;
    using CKSource.FileSystem.Dropbox;
    using CKSource.FileSystem.Local;

    using System;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
    using Microsoft.Owin;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;

    using Owin;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Acl;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Authentication;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;

    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder)
        {
            LoggerManager.LoggerAdapterFactory = new NLogLoggerAdapterFactory();
            ConfigureAuthForIdentity(builder);

            RegisterFileSystems();

            var connectorBuilder = ConfigureConnector();
            var connector = connectorBuilder.Build(new OwinConnectorFactory());
            builder.Map("/CKFinder/connector", builder1 => builder1.UseConnector(connector));
        }

        private void ConfigureAuthForIdentity(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);


        }

        public ConnectorBuilder ConfigureConnector()
        {
            var connectorBuilder = new ConnectorBuilder();
            connectorBuilder
                .SetRequestConfiguration(
                    (request, config) =>
                    {

                        //config.AddProxyBackend("local", new LocalStorage(@"MyFiles"));
                        var userName = request.Principal?.Identity?.Name;
                        if (userName != null)
                        {
                            var sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
                            var hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userName));
                            var folderName = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty);
                            config.AddProxyBackend("local", new LocalStorage(@"c:\files"));
                            config.AddResourceType("private", resourceBuilder => resourceBuilder.SetBackend("local", folderName));
                            config.SetThumbnailBackend("local", "thumbs");                            
                            config.AddAclRule(new AclRule(
                   new StringMatcher("*"), new StringMatcher("/"), new StringMatcher("*"),
                   new Dictionary<Permission, PermissionType>
                   {
                         { Permission.FolderView, PermissionType.Allow },
                         { Permission.FolderCreate, PermissionType.Allow },
                         { Permission.FolderRename, PermissionType.Allow },
                         { Permission.FolderDelete, PermissionType.Allow },

                         { Permission.FileView, PermissionType.Allow },
                         { Permission.FileCreate, PermissionType.Allow },
                         { Permission.FileRename, PermissionType.Allow },
                         { Permission.FileDelete, PermissionType.Allow },


                         { Permission.ImageResize, PermissionType.Allow },
                         { Permission.ImageResizeCustom, PermissionType.Allow }
                   }));
                        }
                    })
                .SetAuthenticator(new MyAuthenticator());

            return connectorBuilder;
        }

        private static void RegisterFileSystems()
        {
            FileSystemFactory.RegisterFileSystem<LocalStorage>();
            FileSystemFactory.RegisterFileSystem<DropboxStorage>();
        }

    }

    public class MyAuthenticator : IAuthenticator
    {
        public Task<CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Authentication.IUser> AuthenticateAsync(ICommandRequest commandRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var user = new User(true, null);
            return Task.FromResult((CKSource.CKFinder.Connector.Core.Authentication.IUser)user);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what change you made other than formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`SetRequestConfiguration`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/class_c_k_source_1_1_c_k_finder_1_1_connector_1_1_core_1_1_builders_1_1_connector_builder.html#a09089b6c7e9d06b9023afd6adda37d67) method of the [`ConnectorBuilder`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/class_c_k_source_1_1_c_k_finder_1_1_connector_1_1_core_1_1_builders_1_1_connector_builder.html) class accepts an action that will be called for each request.

The code from the example you linked, although defined during startup, will be executed for every request.

Additionally you should make sure that the user is already logged in when she is trying to use CKFinder. For example:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var connectorFactory = new OwinConnectorFactory();

        var connectorBuilder = ...

        var connector = connectorBuilder.Build(connectorFactory);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(
            /*
             * Your CookieAuthenticationOptions that will redirect anonymous
             * users to the login page
             */
            );
        app.UseConnector(connector);
    }
}
```

About missing thumbnails, you should add at least one allowed thumbnail size. Just add something like `config.SetThumbnailSizes(new SizeAndQuality(100, 100, new ImageQuality(80)));` to the action executed in `SetRequestConfiguration`.

Comment: Thanks for guiding! I was able to create separate folder per user. Now I am not able to see the thumbnails of the images uploaded. Here is the code that i have so far

Comment: Could you please update your original question to include the code you have right now?

Comment: Not sure what change you made other than formatting?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: hi..it seems like the images inserted do no open in the email. I am saving the text into database which is a sent an email. This is what the url for the image looks like http://domain.../ckfinder/connector?command=Proxy&amp;lang=en&amp;type=private&amp;currentFolder=%2F&amp;hash=acdcccfd691e0e3d1dd1a000c0cde24da987cd36&amp;fileName=Jellyfish.jpg

Not sure if i need to do anything with ACL?

Comment: I see the issue...when the email is opened and the file is requested..it call the same   connectorBuilder
                .SetRequestConfiguration but since it is not logged in..it does not get the access...not sure how to handle this case...